# Place CMS static block before breadcrumbs?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

How is this possible? I know how to do it with two different blocks but I don't know **how to reorder a CMS block with a a module block**.

[image]

Comment: use move element in layout file you move whatever place you want. show your layout file for proper answer? refer this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html

Comment: Which layout file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rearrange elements you need to use the `<move>` tag.

Here's the official documentation about it: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange

In your case I reckon the right code would be something that looks like this:

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="your.static.block.name" destination="page.top" before="breadcrumbs"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Don't forget to change the `element` attribute value with the value of your block name.

Comment: I thought it could be something like that. Thank you very much Raphael.

Comment: Is it okay to use "move" for all of my static blocks in the default layout xml file for my theme? Am I okay to move them if they don't appear on that page or will that throw an error?

Comment: @user3621758 yes I reckon you can. You need to try though

Comment: I did try, it didn't really do anything. Unless I have the container names wrong.

Comment: @user3621758 You can check if the container name is correct by removing it. If it doesn't remove itself then you have the name wrong - <referenceContainer="name.here" remove="true" />